# In India, what is the difference between "local flying area" and "airspace"?

Tags: airspace, dgca-india-regulations

Can anyone define what is a "local flying area" and an "airspace" and what is the difference between the two? It would be good if the definition is as per Indian rules.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE, you have this question tagged as both FAA and DGCA but you are asking about Indian rules in the body. You may want to remove the FAA tags as they are a bit confusing. If you are looking for FAA answers as well you should add that to the body as you may get more answers that way.

Answer (score 1):

A local flying area is airspace that is designated by local air traffic control for general flying not involving circuits and landing. In the US it is something that is loosely referred to as "the practice area." In this area aircraft can perform practice and other maneuvers, and air traffic control will be aware of it and can warn other aircraft to be on the lookout for this. In India it is common for these practice areas to be segregated for flying school aircraft, and medium to heavy aircraft.

To put it another way, all local flying areas are part of a country's airspace, but only a fraction of the airspace is designated as local flying areas. I hope this helps.